# drupal_mail to users selected from database

Tags: database, emails

In my Drupal 7 site I use custom tableselect form to manage some events. User can review profiles of people who applied for event and approve their participation. I want to send them email notification via `drupal_mail` on form submission. I have implemented `hook_form_submit` and added following code

```
foreach ($values as $key => $value){

    $sql = db_select('users', 'u');
    $sql-> fields('u', array('mail'));
    $sql-> condition('uid', $value['uid']);
    $mail = $sql->execute();
    }
    foreach($mail as $m){
    dsm($m);
    drupal_mail('event_manager','event_approved', $m, language_default());
    }
```

But in this case I have an error :

> Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in
>   SmtpMailSystem->mail()

How can I fix the code to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a first glance, it's because you are passing the whole object instead of the email address. Try this:

```
  $sql = db_select('users', 'u');
  $sql-> fields('u', array('mail'));
  $sql-> condition('uid', $value['uid']);
  $mail = $sql->execute();
}
foreach($mail as $m){
  dsm($m);
  drupal_mail('event_manager','event_approved', $m->mail, language_default());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `drupal_mail()` function the third parameter should be the email address to whom you want to send email to.So pass the email address of user instead of $m.